# Filtering tables with a character variable as a column name in dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to filter the mtcars table in R, referencing a column name with a character variable. So, I write:

```
var <- "cyl"
mtcars %>%
  filter(!!var > 6)
```

But, for some reason the table isn't being filtered. I think this code is the equivalent of this:

```
mtcars %>%
  filter("cyl" > 6)
```

What I really need is to convert that string to a name. Does anybody know how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
library(dplyr)

var <- sym("cyl")

mtcars %>%
  filter(!!var > 6)
```